# Wordpress plugins check if using cookies

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing a feature, by visiting website, user will be ask about cookie policy, whether they want to save cookies or not. By rejecting this, i want to deactivate all plugins which uses cookies.

I am able to get all plugins via this.

```
$all_plugins = get_plugins();
```

And also able to deactivate plugin by this.

```
deactivate_plugins( 'test/test.php' );
```

The thing i want to know, how can i check that my installed plugins are using cookies?

Comment: `how can i check that my installed plugins are using cookies?` Either look through the code or dump `$_COOKIES` and have a look

Comment: Also because one user doesn't want cookies you're going to disable all of the plugins for everyone else? Seems like a flaw in your logic...

Comment: @IsThisJavascript how would i know that which cookie belongs to which plugin ?

Comment: @naththedeveloper the best would be to stop that cookie to be saved, but that seems not be an achievable task, rather decided to do this

Comment: Maybe you can clear cookies and see which ones get activated for plugin used. Or just look thru the code.